# Visual Studio Showing Wrong Project Name In Quick Launch

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I've created a .Net 5 Windows Application on VS19 from a previous project, giving it a new solution and project name. The new project/solution is in it's own folder. I've deleted the .vs and obj folders, and yet the Quick Launch button still shows the name of the original project "Stock Level Viewer" instead of "Credit Limit Forecaster" (see image below).

[image]

Is there something I'm still missing?

Comment: This is the style of [start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnQod.png) in my vs2019, which is different from yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the Debug profile still had the previous project name there. Here are the steps to fix it:

1. Go to the project properties.
2. Select the Debug tag.
3. In the Profile field, first click the Delete button ("1" in the image below).
4. Click on the "New..." button ("2" in the image below).
5. Create a new profile name.

[image]